# Bootstrap datepicker ev.date format

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to use https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker. I have already this code:

```
<script>
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate());
   $('#datepicker').ready(function() {
var datum = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 

language: "cs-CZ", 
startDate: date,
format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
todayHighlight: true 
}) 
.on('changeDate', function(ev) {
  var datumy = new Date(ev.date);
  alert(datumy);
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
    $('#datumpick').slideUp(100);
    alert
       $.ajax({
   url: 'http://***********/******.php',
   data: {druh: '30', vyberdatapicker: datumy},
   type: "POST",
   success: function(data){
            $('#result').html(data);   
   }
   });

  });

});
  </script>
```

and this element which call this func.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn" id="datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">Vybrat datum</a>
```

This code works perfectly, but I'm not able get date in right format. If `alert(datumy)` appears, it show me date in this format `Thu Jun 19 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`, but I need this format `2014-06-17`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5nXHX/)**

You are making a new Date object below.  It takes default JS format.

```
var datumy = new Date(ev.date);
```

Instead use

```
var datumy = $('#datepicker').val();
```

---

For this **2014-06-17** format,

```
var datumy = $('#datepicker').val().replace(/\//g,'-');
```

or

```
var datum = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 

   ....
   format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
   ....
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5nXHX/1/)**